# Application does not exit after pressing notification

Tags: android

I started a notification with the code as follows. If i start the Notification from an app with a button, it will start but if i press an 'Exit' button on the same App it will clear the Notification and exit.

However, if i close the App after the Notification up start the app again with the Notification using a PendingIntent. The App 'Exit' button will clear the Notification, but will not exit the app unless it is pressed again.

How can i develop it to clear Notification and exit, regardless of how the App in opened.

Can any one help please, What is wrong with this code?

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bStat:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotifyActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        String body = "This is a Test..";
        String title = "XxxXxx Xxxxx..";
        Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ttsn, body,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi);
        n.defaults = 0;
        // Notification.DEFAULT_ALL
        nm.notify(uniqueID, n);
        break;

    case R.id.bExit:
        nm.cancel(uniqueID);
        finish();
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you initialize your Views and ClickListener when your start the app from the notification?

Comment: How do you do that, im kinda new and the learning curve can be quite steep sometimes.

Comment: It seems to happen however it do it. Whenever a Notification is cleared with notification.cancel(uniqueID) i have to exit program twice with finish()... Any help please, why is this happening....

Comment: Decided to go another way, sorted problem now. Thanks for your help... :-)